# Query User Sessions in Windows

Tags: c#, .net

There is a built-in tool: `query.exe` that allows you to view all active users and sessions in Windows.

It's output looks like:

```
PS C:\> query.exe user
 USERNAME              SESSIONNAME        ID  STATE   IDLE TIME  LOGON TIME
>testusr               console             1  Active      none   12/16/2014 9:29 AM
```

Right now I have code that just parses the `query.exe` output, but some of us are concerned that future OS upgrades might change query's output so we're looking for an API call that can be used instead.

Is there anyway .Net way to gather the same information?

For alternatives, we don't necessary need all the fields, but we do need: Username, State, and Logon Time. We also need to run this code from the System context so any code or WMI classes that requires the user context won't work for us.

Comment: Not sure if there is a .NET API to get the information but one way would be to spawn query.exe through a Process object and read / parse the output.

Comment: I actually do that right now. But some people are concerned that Query's output may change over time and that a direct API call (if found) should be used instead.

Comment: There's possibly a way to get the same information via WMI although I don't know. The output of this is not likely to change unless you upgrade the OS. I'd consider it stable.

Comment: An OS Upgrade is the exact scenario that the others are worried about. WMI might have what we need somewhere, but we didn't have much luck finding a class that enumerated all user sessions.

Comment: Do you need all fields of just some of them?

Comment: All fields is a nice to have, however: Username, State, Login Time are the primary fields we need.

Comment: OK, but OS upgrades are pretty infrequent and don't usually arrive unexpectedly. Is this concern being expressed by an 'enterprise architect' by any chance?

Comment: did you tried WMI o PInvoke ?

Answer (score 2):

Well what I found and I think could be useful for you is [Cassia](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/) project.

There is almost ready for you example in main page:

```
ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
using (ITerminalServer server = manager.GetLocalServer())
{
    server.Open();
    foreach (ITerminalServicesSession session in server.GetSessions())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi there, " + session.UserAccount + " on session " + session.SessionId);
        Console.WriteLine("It looks like you logged on at " + session.LoginTime +
                          " and are now " + session.ConnectionState);
    }
}
```

As you can see when you get a [TerminalServicesSession](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/source/browse/trunk/Source/Cassia/Impl/TerminalServicesSession.cs) you will find UserName, LoginTime and [ConnectionState](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/source/browse/trunk/Source/Cassia/ConnectionState.cs).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: TerminalServicesManager like Terminals https://github.com/Terminals-Origin/Terminals ?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply get the last logon time using WMI:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogonSession"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_LogonSession instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Last Logon: {0}", queryObj["StartTime"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Permissions for Access to ***WMI*** `root\\CIMV2` ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want [`NetWkstaUserEnum`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32.netwkstauserenum). I couldn't find a native .NET version of this but it seems like a fairly light interop call.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll have a look and see what we can get out of it.